# Как сделать сначала сужение, потом перенос элементов Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

HTML:

```
<div class="selector">
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.selector {
        display: flex;
        gap: 20px;
        flex-wrap: wrap; 
        max-width: 90%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
}
.el {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    min-width: 210px;
}
```

Как сделать чтобы при уменьшении размеров экрана сначала сужались блоки до минимальной ширины, а только потом они переносились на новую строку? Всё через flex. Если не получится, можно через grid

Comment: Прочитайте про свойство flex-shrink

Answer (score 0):

```css
.selector {
        display: flex;
        gap: 20px;
        flex-wrap: wrap; 
        max-width: 90%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
}

.selector>*{
    flex: 1 1 50px;
}
.el {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    min-width: 210px;
    background-color: black;
}

span{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="selector">
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>  
  <span class="el"></span> 
</div>
```

.el уменьшается до минимальной ширины, только затем переносится на новую строку

```css
.selector {
        display: flex;
        gap: 20px;
        flex-wrap: wrap; 
        max-width: 90%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
}

.selector>*{
    flex: 1 1 50px;
}
.el {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    min-width: 210px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="selector">
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Последний блок растягивается на всю ширину. При помощи флексов можно как-то убрать и сделать обычного размера?

Comment: Ничто не мешает последнему блоку занять всю ширину, для этого метода нужно добавить еще один блок

Comment: Ну а как-то можно сделать чтобы было сжатие до определённого размера, а потом перенос без растягивания последнего элемента?

Comment: Попробуй, должно сработать
<span class="el"></span> 
span{
    visibility: hidden;
}

Comment: visibility: hidden просто скрывает ведь элемент

Comment: Но последний блок также сжимается до минимальной ширины, как и первые два.